# Null pointer Exception in Android when using Glide

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-glide

Here is the logcat output

```
2022-06-20 13:19:27.605 20830-20830/com.example.moveapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.moveapplication, PID: 20830
java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
    at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:29)
    at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:23)
    at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:768)
    at com.example.moveapplication.activities.MainActivity.openBottomSheetDialog$lambda-2(MainActivity.kt:100)
    at com.example.moveapplication.activities.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$acEx44X-0qqDdGYpms4KzfGag5A(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.example.moveapplication.activities.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.onSuccess(Unknown Source:15)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

From my logcat the exception occurs when using Glide to load image.
**Line 100** is `.into(uImage)`

```
 private fun openBottomSheetDialog(position: Int) {
    val uImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.sheetIvProfileImage)
    val uNumber = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sheetTvOwnerNumber)
    val uEmail = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvOwnerEmail)
    val uAbout = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvOwnerAbout)
    val uTitle = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sheetTvOwnerTitle)
    val publisher = posts[position].publisher

    val ownersRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("owners").document(publisher)
    ownersRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
        val ownerModel = document.toObject(Owner::class.java)
        if (ownerModel != null) {
            Glide.with(this)
                .load(ownerModel.profileImage)
                .into(uImage)
        }
        uTitle.text = ownerModel?.username
        uNumber.text = ownerModel?.phoneNumber
        uEmail.text = ownerModel?.email
        uAbout.text = ownerModel?.about
    }

    val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme)
    val bottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext).inflate(
            R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog,
            findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet)
    )
    bottomSheetDialog.apply {
        setContentView(bottomSheetView)
        setCancelable(true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Are these `View`s, i.e., `uImage`, `uName`, etc. the part of `BottomSheet` or `Activity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you're initializing the `View`s of `BottomSheet` wrong.
If I'm not wrong, you're trying to show this `BottomSheet` inside an `Activity`, if yes, try the below code:

```
    private fun openBottomSheetDialog(position: Int) {
        // Initialize the View of the BottomSheet
        val bottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog, findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet), false)
        // Initialize the BottomSheetDialog
        val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme).apply {
            setCancelable(true)
            // Set the View
            setContentView(bottomSheetView)
        }
        /*
        * To initialize the Views of BottomSheet,
        * use parent view of the BottomSheet, i.e., bottomSheetView
        * */
        val uImage = bottomSheetView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.sheetIvProfileImage)
        val uNumber = bottomSheetView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sheetTvOwnerNumber)
        val uEmail = bottomSheetView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvOwnerEmail)
        val uAbout = bottomSheetView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvOwnerAbout)
        val uTitle = bottomSheetView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sheetTvOwnerTitle)
        val publisher = posts[position].publisher

        val ownersRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("owners").document(publisher)
        ownersRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            val ownerModel = document.toObject(Owner::class.java)
            if (ownerModel != null) {
                Glide.with(this)
                    .load(ownerModel.profileImage)
                    .into(uImage)
                // These Views should be inside
                uTitle.text = ownerModel?.username
                uNumber.text = ownerModel?.phoneNumber
                uEmail.text = ownerModel?.email
                uAbout.text = ownerModel?.about
            }
        }
        
        // Add this line to show the BottomSheet
        bottomSheetDialog.show()
    }
```

Comment: I have used your refractored code and the good news is my app does not crash. Bad news is the bottomsheetdialog is not showing. Basically nothing happens when I call the `openBottomSheet` method after onClick

Comment: Hey man, I updated my answer, please check at the end of the method. Actually, I forgot to call `show()` for the `BottomSheet`

Comment: It worked correctly

Comment: Great, please give +1 point or upvote my answer, it would be nice, thanks :-).

Answer (score 0):

`this` in `Glide.with(this)` it represent what ?
You should to pass a view or a context there

```
Glide.with(requireContext())  //for example
.load(ownerModel.profileImage)
.into(uImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell where the null is exactly because we don't have your project but you do, so a breakpoint would have clarified this for you and everyone else.

```
ownersRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
        val ownerModel = document.toObject(Owner::class.java)
        if (ownerModel != null) {
            Glide.with(this)
                .load(ownerModel.profileImage)
                .into(uImage)
        }
```

In this code, there can be various nulls.

`ownerRef` you do `get()` on firebase, but are you sure that's not null?

`this` in `Glide.with(...)` this there likely refers to the anonymous instance of `addOnSuccessListener` in the lambda, so not the Activity or Fragment.

`ownerModel` is not null because you check

`uImage` could be null, but I don't know if Glide cares.

Put a breakpoint, debug your app, and notice you have a NullPointerReference exception.